# Identify if button was pressed on M5StickC Plus?

Tags: python, esp32

In a while loop data is sent from server to client. The loop just keeps running and sending data, even though button B was pressed on M5StickC Plus.

I tried different methods to break out of the while loop (global variables, ....)
however, none of them works.

It was suggested to use WiFi.setSleep(false);
It doesn't appear to be available for M5StickC Plus however???

```
while True:
    s.send(data.encode())

    if not btnB.wasPressed():
        pass
    else:
        break
```